# Proper use of sequence parameter in loops

Tags: blazor

This [post](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ec232992c2446ab9a0059dd0fbc5d0c3) indicates I should be using hard coded values. However it does not spell out how to deal with loops. What is the correct way? Does using `builder.SetKey(model);` circumnavigate the problem? The code is working without issue. I just want to clear this up before making a repo public for this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ModelToComponentMapper/)

```
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {

            ...

            int i = 3;
            foreach (object model in models)
            {
                (Type componentType, string propertyName) viewComponentInfo = GetModelViewComponentInfo(model);

                Type componentType = viewComponentInfo.componentType;
                if (componentType is not null)
                {
                    string propertyName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewComponentInfo.propertyName) ? "Model" : viewComponentInfo.propertyName;
                    builder.OpenComponent(i++, componentType);
                    builder.AddAttribute(i++, propertyName, model);
                    builder.SetKey(model);
                    builder.CloseComponent();
                }
            }
            ...
        }
```

Comment: You are doing exactly what that post says you should _not_.  I am not sure its harmful here but note that SetKey() and i++ (inside the loop) are kind of redundant.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I realise this. That is what/why I am asking. I put the SetKey in because I was not sure about the sequence issue. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'll make it  an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing exactly what that post says you should not.

To quote the page you linked to:

> Q: Despite this, I still want to generate the sequence numbers dynamically. Can I?
> A: You can, but it will make your app performance worse.

The advice tells you to use:

```
// int i = 3;

foreach(...)
{
   ...
   builder.OpenComponent(3, componentType);
   builder.AddAttribute(4, propertyName, model);
   builder.SetKey(model);
}
```

A little counter-intuitive but the numbering is there to maintain information about loops and if/else branches.  SetKey() helps to identify the iterations of the foreach loop.

As far as I can tell it will only matter if your models collection changes at runtime, I'm not sure if that's the case for your package.

But I would err on the safe side and manually number those lines.

Comment: Thankyou. I did try this and it worked as well, it just looked wrong. I note others are asking the same further down in that link and did not get a response.

Comment: Yes, that page would have been better with a loop as example instead of an if/else.

Comment: This is a great answer, I would just add that the sequence will be ignored because you are using SetKey - as soon as you use a Key, the sequence is ignored. However, it is still required to provide one, so doing it "correctly" like this is the way to go!

Comment: @Mister Magoo This would explain why I saw no discernible difference in all the methods I tried. Thanks again to you both for clearing this up for me.